# I want to make my discord bot status change

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

i want to make my discord bot status change every 10 sec, between "watching x servers", to "watching x users", here's my code.

```js
client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log("Conectat ca si: " + client.user.tag);
  client.user.setActivity(`${client.guilds.cache.size} servere | .help`, {
    type: "WATCHING",
    }, 60000);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
client.on("ready", () => {
    let currentActivity = 0;
    let maxActivity = 1;

    setInterval(async () => {
        currentActivity++;
        if (currentActivity > maxActivity) {currentActivity = 0};
        switch(currentActivity) {
            case 0:
                client.user.setActivity(`${client.guilds.cache.size} servers.`, {type: "WATCHING"})
                break;
            case 1:
                client.user.setActivity(`${client.users.cache.size} users.`, {type: "WATCHING"})
                break;
        };
    }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks again Jakye, you always help, its working :)